# I need the center of the image on the center of the screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uiimage

how to fix the image on the center of the screen regardless of the positionI need to fix compass in the middle of any screen

this is my code

```
_backgroundImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"background.jpg"]];

    [self.view addSubview:_backgroundImageView];

    CGPoint centerImageView = _backgroundImageView.center;
    centerImageView.x = self.view.center.x;
    _backgroundImageView.center = centerImageView;
```

But the image is fixed on the left side, I need to not depending on the position of the screen centered in

Now only the right position varies
 [image]
Now only the right position varies
[image]
I need the center of the image on the center of the screen
[image]

Comment: are you using autolayout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is very simple

My actions:

Step 1

```
_backgroundImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"background.jpg"];
[self.view sendSubviewToBack:self.backgroundImageView];
```

Step 2
[image]

Step 3
[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is one way to do it:

on viewDidLoad:

```
_backgroundImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"background.jpg"]];
[self.view addSubview:_backgroundImageView];

CGRect bgImageFrame = _backgroundImageView.frame;
bgImageFrame.origin.x = (self.view.frame.size.width / 2.0) - (bgImageFrame.size.width / 2.0);
bgImageFrame.origin.y = (self.view.frame.size.height / 2.0) - (bgImageFrame.size.height / 2.0);
_backgroundImageView.frame = bgImageFrame;
```

then this method is called everytime the screen rotates:

```
- (void)viewWillTransitionToSize:(CGSize)size withTransitionCoordinator:(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator>)coordinator {
    [coordinator animateAlongsideTransition:^(id  _Nonnull context) {

        CGRect bgImageFrame = _backgroundImageView.frame;
        bgImageFrame.origin.x = (self.view.frame.size.width / 2.0) - (bgImageFrame.size.width / 2.0);
        bgImageFrame.origin.y = (self.view.frame.size.height / 2.0) - (bgImageFrame.size.height / 2.0);
        _backgroundImageView.frame = bgImageFrame;

    } completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: Thanks  Filipe Sá, 
but how to make the left side of the floating.

-top,right, left bottom -floating...

how to set center of the image on the center of the screen

Comment: I'm not sure if that's what you're asking, but i edited my answer so it centers the image every time the screen rotates

Answer (score 0):

use this code may be help u.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {

  _backgroundImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"background.jpg"]];
     [self.view addSubview:_backgroundImageView];
}

-(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {

    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];

    CGPoint centerImageView = _backgroundImageView.center;
    centerImageView.x = self.view.center.x;
    _backgroundImageView.center = centerImageView;
}
```